# Private variable disappears after thread starts

Tags: multithreading, qt, pthreads, qt5

**Problem:**

I have a private variable that is available during the startup of a threaded object, but is out of scope when it is used later (via a signal and slot call).

**Details:**

I have an application that I'm developing in Qt5 for both linux and windows.
Currently it works as expected under linux (where development began), but now
that I'm trying to stand it up on windows 7 (I didn't have a copy of windows initially) I have run into this problem where (on windows only) my private variables go out of scope after the thread initializes.

**Question:**

What is wrong with my object/thread structure such that the variable scope is fine under Linux, but not in windows? I thought that was the kind of "behind the scenes" stuff Qt took care of? (clearly not)

**More Detail:**

The order of operation goes like this

1. Instantiate an object
2. Move the object into a thread
3. Get the thread's start signal and call an init function in the object
4. Later, get data and emit a signal to the threaded object
5. Threaded object processes data

The code outlining the steps above is summarized below.

```
void MyWorkerClass::init()
{
    // ... bunchOCode
    procThread = new QThread;                   // <-- procThread - private to MyWorkerClass
    procObj    = new Processor(startupData);    // <-- procObj - private to MyWorkerClass
    procObj->moveToThread(procThread);
    connect(procThread,  SIGNAL(started()),           procObj,    SLOT(doStart()));
    connect(this,        SIGNAL(dataIsReady(void *)), procObj,    SLOT(processMsgs(void *)));
    procThread->start();
    ok = waitforProcSetup();
    // ... Life is good, do more stuff
}

class Processor : public QObject
{
    // ... Other
    // ... stuff
    private slots:
        void doStart();
        void processMsgs(void * buffer);
    private:
        QHash<QString, bool> process;
}

void Processor::doStart()                   // <-- private slot 
{
    // ... take care of init stuff that couldn't be done in constructor
    // Variable is valid here and I can work with it.
    foreach(site, locations.uniqueKeys()) {
        process[site]    = true;           // <-- works like a champ
        qDebug() << QString("%1 => %2").arg(site).arg(process[site]);
    }
}

void Processor::processMsgs(void * buffer)   // <-- buffer is malloc'd memory and works fine
{
    // ... When MyWorkerClass gets some data it emits a signal that is connected
    //     to this private slot.
    // Simply trying to examine the variable causes a segfault (because it's uninitialized here)
     qDebug() << "... processMsgs:" << process.isEmpty();   // <-- wets the bed
}
.
```

Comment: But we cannot see how you signal dataIsReady.

Comment: You need to keep minimizing your code (by throwing unneeded parts) until what's left is just enough to reproduce the problem. Then update your question with such minimized code. Make sure it fits into one file (main.cpp). If you have any slots, add '#include "main.moc"` at the very end of the file.

Comment: "private variables go out of scope after the thread initializes." What do you mean by that? What is the error? Remember: we can't read your mind. We don't know much, if anything, about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to improve my question, by following the suggestions from the people who commented, I found out what was going on. I was working on creating a small working version of the example I posted (thanks Kuba Ober). The "error" I was encountering was a segmentation fault that could consistently be recreated with the debug line:

```
qDebug() << "... processMsgs:" << process.isEmpty();   // <-- wets the bed
```

Specifically, the private QHash variable "process" was useable when I called it the first time (after the thread was up and running)

```
connect(procThread,  SIGNAL(started()),           procObj,    SLOT(doStart()));
```

but that same variable acted like it had gone out of scope when I tried to call it the second time

```
connect(this,        SIGNAL(dataIsReady(void *)), procObj,    SLOT(processMsgs(void *)));
```

The signal (dataIsReady(void *)) for this second call is an explicit "emit" that the worker class does when it's collected some data that can be processed. I tried to make that clear in the comments of the example pseudocode, but I didn't take into account that the comment code I included wouldn't stand out that well since it's all grey.

What was really going on was right after I filled "process[site]" with data I also looped over a quint64 array filling it with data too. The loop went 1 element too far and wrote into the "process" variable, making it look to me like it had gone out of scope. In linux it was purely coincidental that it didn't segfault (likely there was padding between the array and the QHash), but the windows runtime exposed the error for the first time.

Comment: Such questions and answers are useless to anyone but yourself. They don't belong here. Besides, the problem is a simple typo and that makes it automatically off-topic, and you're not showing relevant code - that makes it doubly off-topic. "I also looped over a quint64 array filling it with data too. The loop went 1 element too far" So, you wrote a C loop, not a C++ loop. That's a rather typical problem. C++ code shouldn't generally look like C :)